# Firebase authentication for web works only on the second time

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have a website that reads/writes data from/to Google's firebase. I have both anonymous and email authentication enabled. Any user can view the data anonymously. But to write/edit the data, the user must sign in using his id.

I have a login form that gets user credentials and authenticates the user. On page load, the login form signs out of firebase from the anonymous id.[image] It then waits for user credentials and button click. The login button onclick event verifies the user credential with firebase and authenticates the user. However, the authentication only works on the second attempt. The first attempt always gives an error.  (It's not because of wrong email id or password).[image]
In the console, I print the email id, password and any warning message during authentication. It always gives a network error but logs in immediately on the second attempt. Does anyone know the reason?

This problem also continues inside my website when I try to read data from firebase and display it on the page. The page is supposed to display contents on load but it is not displaying any contents. Even though the corresponding functions are executed (I think firebase returns an empty query). It displays content if I trigger the function manually (second time).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> auth.signout()

is called on the page load.

Comment: Yes, because the website authenticates everyone as an anonymous user on page load. Sign in with respective user credentials is optional and when the user wants to sign in, I first sign them out from their anonymous id before authenticating them with their actual id.